# How to generate a sequence between two values in java?

Tags: java, sequence, sequence-generators

The two values that i have are:

```
firstval=200.000 
Secondval=399.999,
```

I have to generate a numbers such that when the first decimal part should  get incremented till `999` for the  integral part, next the integral part should be incremented and then decimal part resets to `000` and starts incrementing for the new number . And this happens till `399`.
Like

> 200.001,200.002.....200.999,201.000,201.002....399.998,399.999"

Comment: A for loop that increments by .001?

Comment: When you have integers like 200000 to 399999, you can use a for loop for that and divide the index by 1000

Answer (score 5):

There is a nice way to get required array with Java 8 Stream API

(1) Use double incrementation

```
 double[] sequence = DoubleStream.iterate(200.0, d -> d + 0.001).limit((int) (1 + (399.999 - 200.0) / 0.001)).toArray();
```

Note, that summing up lots of doubles will likely give some error, for example on my laptop the last number in the sequence is `399.99899999686227`

(2) Better way is to generate integer stream and map it to doubles:

```
 double[] sequence = IntStream.range(200000, 400000).mapToDouble( i -> i * 0.001).toArray();
```

In this case no error from adding multiple doubles will be accumulated

Answer (score 2):

```
double start = 200.0;
double end = 399.999;
double increment = 0.001;

for (double v = start; v < end + increment / 2; v += increment) {
    System.out.printf("%.3f\n", v);
}
```

Comment: just wonder how did you know the accumulated addition of `0.001` is not going to make the last number larger than `399.99` due to approximation of floating point number?

Comment: I did know, but printf will round it anyway.  This was an easy question, and there's no need to overcomplicate things at this stage...

Comment: obviously you are unaware of pitfalls of floating point calculations. As floating number cannot always accurately represent decimal number, it is possible that after bunch of calculations, the last number (399.99 in this example) will be something slightly larger (399.99000000000001, just a make-up example).  This `v` should be included in the sequence but it will now be skipped because it is larger than 399.99 (although it should be treated as equals)

Comment: Please, don't presume to know what I know.  I'm very much aware, but I deemed this quite off topic for this question.

Comment: No it is not off topic. That's why I asked in the first comment.  Such way of generating sequence may cause the last value in the sequence missing, For which means giving wrong result.

Comment: That means you really don't understand my concern. How about I change the question a little bit: use your approach to print sequence from 100.0 to 100.999 (inclusive), with 0.001 increments? Note the missing 100.99 that you encounter?

Comment: You finally managed to communicate the real issue.  It was potentially missing the LAST value (399.999 or 100.999, note the triple 9 decimal digits).  You're comments confused me as I'm 100% certain it won't skip values at such a low number of significant digits (for doubles that will become an issue at around 15 digits).  I've adjusted the code accordingly.

Comment: I have been saying the same issue from very beginning ("last number") ....

Comment: Except the last number is 399.999 not 399.99 (there's another 9 numbers after that one).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
public static void counterGenerator(double start, double end) {
    DecimalFormat counterInDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    String counterInString = counterInDecimalFormat.format(start);
    System.out.println(counterInString); // This is the counter in String format.
    double counter = Double.parseDouble(counterInString);
    if (counter < end)
        counterGenerator(start + 0.001, end);
    return;
}
```

In the above example, you have your counter in `String` format in the variable called `counterInString`

But you need not worry about the problems associated with incrementing a `Double` which is actual residing in a `String` variable. In the code, you can see the incrementing task is being done by a `double counter` which gets convert back to `String` by using the `DecimalFormat` class.

Here keeping your counter as a `String` helps you to retain the `0s` after decimal in numbers like `200.000`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No offence, but don't you think that this is too complex or non efficient for this purpose?