# Best way to generate a List<Double> sequence of values given start, end, and step?

Tags: java, double, sequence

I'm actually very surprised I was unable to find the answer to this here, though maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms or something. Closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629114/how-to-generate-a-sequence-between-two-values-in-java), but they ask about generating a specific range of `double`s with a specific step size, and the answers treat it as such. I need something that will generate the numbers with arbitrary start, end and step size.

I figure there *has* to be some method like this in a library somewhere already, but if so I wasn't able to find it easily (again, maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms or something). So here's what I've cooked up on my own in the last few minutes to do this:

```java
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DoubleSequenceGenerator {


     /**
     * Generates a List of Double values beginning with `start` and ending with
     * the last step from `start` which includes the provided `end` value.
     **/
    public static List<Double> generateSequence(double start, double end, double step) {
        Double numValues = (end-start)/step + 1.0;
        List<Double> sequence = new ArrayList<Double>(numValues.intValue());

        sequence.add(start);
        for (int i=1; i < numValues; i++) {
          sequence.add(start + step*i);
        }

        return sequence;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a List of Double values beginning with `start` and ending with
     * the last step from `start` which includes the provided `end` value.
     * 
     * Each number in the sequence is rounded to the precision of the `step`
     * value. For instance, if step=0.025, values will round to the nearest
     * thousandth value (0.001).
     **/
    public static List<Double> generateSequenceRounded(double start, double end, double step) {

        if (step != Math.floor(step)) {
            Double numValues = (end-start)/step + 1.0;
            List<Double> sequence = new ArrayList<Double>(numValues.intValue());

            double fraction = step - Math.floor(step);
            double mult = 10;
            while (mult*fraction < 1.0) {
                mult *= 10;
            }

            sequence.add(start);
            for (int i=1; i < numValues; i++) {
              sequence.add(Math.round(mult*(start + step*i))/mult);
            }

            return sequence;
        }

        return generateSequence(start, end, step);
    }

}
```

These methods run a simple loop multiplying the `step` by the sequence index and adding to the `start` offset. This mitigates compounding floating-point errors which would occur with continuous incrementation (such as adding the `step` to a variable on each iteration).

I added the `generateSequenceRounded` method for those cases where a fractional step size can cause noticeable floating-point errors. It does require a bit more arithmetic, so in extremely performance sensitive situations such as ours, it's nice to have the option of using the simpler method when the rounding is unnecessary. I suspect that in most general use cases the rounding overhead would be negligible.

Note that I intentionally excluded logic for handling "abnormal" arguments such as `Infinity`, `NaN`, `start` > `end`, or a negative `step` size for simplicity and desire to focus on the question at hand.

Here's some example usage and corresponding output:

```
System.out.println(DoubleSequenceGenerator.generateSequence(0.0, 2.0, 0.2))
System.out.println(DoubleSequenceGenerator.generateSequenceRounded(0.0, 2.0, 0.2));
System.out.println(DoubleSequenceGenerator.generateSequence(0.0, 102.0, 10.2));
System.out.println(DoubleSequenceGenerator.generateSequenceRounded(0.0, 102.0, 10.2));
```

```
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2000000000000002, 1.4000000000000001, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
[0.0, 10.2, 20.4, 30.599999999999998, 40.8, 51.0, 61.199999999999996, 71.39999999999999, 81.6, 91.8, 102.0]
[0.0, 10.2, 20.4, 30.6, 40.8, 51.0, 61.2, 71.4, 81.6, 91.8, 102.0]
```

Is there an existing library that provides this kind of functionality already?

If not, are there any issues with my approach?

Does anyone have a better approach to this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sequences can be easily generated using Java 11 Stream API.

The straightforward approach is to use `DoubleStream`:

```
public static List<Double> generateSequenceDoubleStream(double start, double end, double step) {
  return DoubleStream.iterate(start, d -> d <= end, d -> d + step)
      .boxed()
      .collect(toList());
}
```

On ranges with a large number of iterations, `double` precision error could accumulate resulting in bigger error closer to the end of the range.
The error can be minimised by switching to `IntStream` and using integers and single double multiplier:

```
public static List<Double> generateSequenceIntStream(int start, int end, int step, double multiplier) {
  return IntStream.iterate(start, i -> i <= end, i -> i + step)
      .mapToDouble(i -> i * multiplier)
      .boxed()
      .collect(toList());
}
```

To get rid of a `double` precision error at all, `BigDecimal` can be used:

```
public static List<Double> generateSequenceBigDecimal(BigDecimal start, BigDecimal end, BigDecimal step) {
  return Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.compareTo(end) <= 0, d -> d.add(step))
      .mapToDouble(BigDecimal::doubleValue)
      .boxed()
      .collect(toList());
}
```

Examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(generateSequenceDoubleStream(0.0, 2.0, 0.2));
  //[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5999999999999999, 1.7999999999999998, 1.9999999999999998]

  System.out.println(generateSequenceIntStream(0, 20, 2, 0.1));
  //[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2000000000000002, 1.4000000000000001, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]

  System.out.println(generateSequenceBigDecimal(new BigDecimal("0"), new BigDecimal("2"), new BigDecimal("0.2")));
  //[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
}
```

Method [iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#iterate(double,java.util.function.DoublePredicate,java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator)) with this signature (3 parameters) was added in Java 9. So, for Java 8 the code looks like

```
DoubleStream.iterate(start, d -> d + step)
    .limit((int) (1 + (end - start) / step))
```

Comment: This is better approach.

Comment: I'm seeing several compilation errors (JDK 1.8.0): `error: method iterate in interface DoubleStream cannot be applied to given types;
      return DoubleStream.iterate(start, d -> d <= end, d -> d + step)
  required: double,DoubleUnaryOperator.
  found: double,(d)->d <= end,(d)->d + step.
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`. Similar errors for `IntStream.iterate` and `Stream.iterate`. Also, `non-static method doubleValue() cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: @NanoWizard extended the answer with a sample for Java 8

Comment: The three-argument iterator was added in Java 9

Comment: Note that the basic iterative method I proposed [appears to be the fastest solution in the limited benchmarks I've done](https://paiza.io/projects/ZlnwcjhvpEcxP2KPKQRfLw?language=java) by roughly a factor of 2. The `IntStream` and `DoubleStream` approaches are significantly more efficient than solutions using `BigDecimal`s.

Comment: For such micro benchmarks it's better to use https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Absolutely. I just threw that up here because it can easily be shared and run. Can't do that with jmh AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Me personally, I would shorten the **DoubleSequenceGenerator** class up a bit for other goodies and use only one ***sequence generator*** method that contains the option to utilize whatever desired precision wanted or utilize no precision at all:

In the generator method below, if nothing (or any value **less than** 0) is supplied to the optional **setPrecision** parameter then no decimal precision rounding is carried out. If **0** is supplied for a precision value then the numbers are rounded to their nearest **whole** number (ie:  89.674 is rounded to 90.0). If a specific precision value **greater than 0** is supplied then values are converted to that decimal precision.

BigDecimal is used here for...well....precision:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class DoubleSequenceGenerator {

     public static List<Double> generateSequence(double start, double end, 
                                          double step, int... setPrecision) {
        int precision = -1;
        if (setPrecision.length > 0) {
            precision = setPrecision[0];
        }
        List<Double> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double val = start; val < end; val+= step) {
            if (precision > -1) {
                sequence.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(val).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue());
            }
            else {
                sequence.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(val).doubleValue());
            }
        }
        if (sequence.get(sequence.size() - 1) < end) { 
            sequence.add(end); 
        }
        return sequence;
    }    

    // Other class goodies here ....
}
```

And in main():

```
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 2.0, 0.2));
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 2.0, 0.2, 0));
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 2.0, 0.2, 1));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 102.0, 10.2, 0));
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 102.0, 10.2, 0));
System.out.println(generateSequence(0.0, 102.0, 10.2, 1));
```

And the console displays:

```
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6000000000000001, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5999999999999999, 1.7999999999999998, 1.9999999999999998, 2.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]

[0.0, 10.2, 20.4, 30.599999999999998, 40.8, 51.0, 61.2, 71.4, 81.60000000000001, 91.80000000000001, 102.0]
[0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 31.0, 41.0, 51.0, 61.0, 71.0, 82.0, 92.0, 102.0]
[0.0, 10.2, 20.4, 30.6, 40.8, 51.0, 61.2, 71.4, 81.6, 91.8, 102.0]
```

Comment: Interesting ideas, though I see a few issues.

1. By adding to `val` on each iteration, you are getting additive precision loss. For very large sequences, the error on the last few numbers could be significant.

2. Repeated calls to `BigDecimal.valueOf()` are relatively expensive. You'll get better performance (and precision) by converting the inputs to `BigDecimal`s, and using `BigDecimal` for `val`. In fact, by using a `double` for `val`, you aren't really getting any precision benefit from using `BigDecimal` except perhaps with the rounding.

Answer (score 3):

1. > Is there an existing library that provides this kind of functionality already?

   Sorry, I don't know, but judging by other answers, and their relative simplicity - no, there isn't. No need. Well, almost...
2. > If not, are there any issues with my approach?

   Yes and no. You have at least one bug, and some room for performance boost, but the approach itself is correct.

   1. Your bug: rounding error (just change `while (mult*fraction < 1.0)` to `while (mult*fraction < 10.0)` and that should fix it)
   2. All the others do not reach the `end`... well, maybe they just weren't observant enough to read comments in your code
   3. All the others are slower.
   4. Just changing condition in the main loop from `int < Double` to `int < int` will noticeably increase the speed of your code
3. > Does anyone have a better approach to this?

   Hmm... In what way?

   1. Simplicity? `generateSequenceDoubleStream` of @Evgeniy Khyst looks quite simple. And should be used... but maybe no, because of next two points
   2. Precise? `generateSequenceDoubleStream` is not! But still can be saved with the pattern `start + step*i`.
      And `start + step*i` pattern is precise. Only `BigDouble` and fixed-point arithmetic can beat it. But `BigDouble`s are slow, and manual fixed-point arithmetic is tedious and may be inappropriate for your data.
      By the way, on the matters of precision, you can entertain yourself with this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
   3. Speed... well now we are on shaky grounds.
      Check out this repl https://repl.it/repls/RespectfulSufficientWorker
      I do not have a decent test stand right now, so I used repl.it... which is totally inadequate for performance testing, but it's not the main point. The point is - there is no definite answer. Except that maybe in your case, which is not totally clear from you question, you definitely should not use BigDecimal (read further).

      I've tried to play and optimize for big inputs. And your original code, with some minor changes - the fastest. But maybe you need enormous amounts of small `List`s? Then that can be a totally different story.

      This code is quite simple to my taste, and fast enough:

   ```
       public static List<Double> genNoRoundDirectToDouble(double start, double end, double step) {
       int len = (int)Math.ceil((end-start)/step) + 1;
       var sequence = new ArrayList<Double>(len);
       sequence.add(start);
       for (int i=1 ; i < len ; ++i) sequence.add(start + step*i);
       return sequence;
       }
   ```

   If you prefer a more elegant way (or we should call it idiomatic), I, personally, would suggest:

   ```
   public static List<Double> gen_DoubleStream_presice(double start, double end, double step) {
       return IntStream.range(0, (int)Math.ceil((end-start)/step) + 1)
           .mapToDouble(i -> start + i * step)
           .boxed()
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
   ```

   Anyway, possible performance boosts are:

   1. Try switching from `Double` to `double`, and if you really need them, you can switch back again, judging by the tests, it still may be faster. (But don't trust my, try it yourself with your data in your environment. As I said - repl.it sucks for benchmarks)
   2. A little magic: separate loop for `Math.round()`... maybe it has something to do with data locality. I do not recommend this - result is very unstable. But it's fun.

      ```
      double[] sequence = new double[len];
      for (int i=1; i < len; ++i) sequence[i] = start + step*i;
      List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(len);
      list.add(start);
      for (int i=1; i < len; ++i) list.add(Math.round(sequence[i])/mult);
      return list;
      ```
   3. You should definitely consider to be more lazy and generate numbers on demand without storing then in `List`s
4. > I suspect that in most general use cases the rounding overhead would be negligible.

   If you suspect something - test it :-) My answer is "Yes", but again... don't believe me. Test it.

So, back to the main question: Is there an better way?
Yes, of course!
But it depends.

1. Choose **Big**Decimal if you need very **big** numbers **and** very **small** numbers. But if you cast them back to `Double`, and more than that, use it with numbers of "close" magnitude - no need for them! Checkout the same repl: https://repl.it/repls/RespectfulSufficientWorker - last test shows that there will be **no difference in results**, but a dig loss in speed.
2. Make some micro-optimizations based on your data properties, your task, and your environment.
3. Prefer short and simple code if there is not to much to gain from performance boost of 5-10%. Don't waist your time
4. Maybe use fixed-point arithmetic if you can and if it's worth it.

Other than that, you are fine.

**PS**. There's also a Kahan Summation Formula implementation in the repl... just for fun. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1346 and it works - you **can** mitigate summation errors

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static List<Double> generateSequenceRounded(double start, double end, double step) {
    long mult = (long) Math.pow(10, BigDecimal.valueOf(step).scale());
    return DoubleStream.iterate(start, d -> (double) Math.round(mult * (d + step)) / mult)
                .limit((long) (1 + (end - start) / step)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here,

```
int java.math.BigDecimal.scale()
```

Returns the scale of this BigDecimal. If zero or positive, the scale is the number of digits to the right ofthe decimal point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale. For example, a scale of -3 means the unscaled value is multiplied by 1000.

In main()

```
System.out.println(generateSequenceRounded(0.0, 102.0, 10.2));
System.out.println(generateSequenceRounded(0.0, 102.0, 10.24367));
```

And Output:

```
[0.0, 10.2, 20.4, 30.6, 40.8, 51.0, 61.2, 71.4, 81.6, 91.8, 102.0]
[0.0, 10.24367, 20.48734, 30.73101, 40.97468, 51.21835, 61.46202, 71.70569, 81.94936, 92.19303]
```